# Why was this question closed and downvoted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, vote-to-reopen

[What is happening at a specific part in Harry Potter - The Deathly Hallows?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/40909/what-is-happening-at-a-specific-part-in-harry-potter-the-deathly-hallows)

I'm specifically referring to the question version AFTER my edits that made it (hopefully) clear that he was asking for a very specific scene - and my answer proving that the scene was easily and clearly identifiable as a correct answer.

Comment: I disagree on it being closed.  It's pretty specific, so I voted to reopen. However, if I could downvote it a second time, I would. The OP appears to have registered for no other reason than to ask questions about a movie they haven't bothered to watch, and which they apparently have no intention of watching. If ever there were better examples of "this question does not show any research effort", I haven't seen them. It does sound like they're using (abusing) our site to try to answer a trivia contest.

Comment: @Beofett - I watched the movie, and that didn't help me in answering the question **at all**. Just fyi.

Comment: I'm sure I couldn't answer most of it, having seen the movie and having read the book.  However, this part is quite easily answered by viewing/reading: "I want to know the plot details, conclusion, and what is happening in a movie called Harry Potter - The Deathly Hallows." However, I agree that this question is not nearly as bad as their previous one.

Comment: @Beofett - he wasn't asking about the whole movie, just that scene. That's just bad English.

Comment: Fair enough.  You've convinced me to remove my downvote.  I'm not removing my vote to reopen, though ;)